# php5 on LAMP does not show all errors with E_ALL

Tags: php, reporting, lamp

this kinda weird, i have been working on LAMP and suddenly realized that my php.ini files
placed in
"/etc/php5/cli" and "/etc/php/apache2" has Display errors as On and with error reporting set to E_ALL.

As per my knowledge this simple code below should give an error

```
<?
echo "hello";

header('location:http://google.com');

?>
```

The error that i expect to come should be

> hello Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
>   by (output started at writecodeonline.com/php:1) on line 3

but it does not shows the error rather open google.com

Comment: what about `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` ?

Comment: have YOU restarted apache after this modification?

Comment: did both. nothing, i am 4+years developer, i am aware of both of those.
check the links for php.ini file

Comment: Does `phpinfo()` confirm that `display_errors` is enabled, and that error reporting value is set to E_ALL?

Comment: @Jocelyn http://awesomescreenshot.com/0caixwy1f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably enabled the output buffering.

Try set `output_buffering = Off`